# Publishing terminates with Warning: The request was aborted: The request was canceled

Tags: visual-studio-2013, azure-cloud-services, azure-sdk-.net

After upgrading by Azure SDk from version 2.5 to 2.9.I am unable to publish any packages through visual studio.The publish starts then shows warning

> Warning: Request was Aborted:Request was Canceled

I have waited for more than 3 hours but this warning keep poping up and nothing seems to upload.
I am using windows 8.1, visual studio 2013 Ultimate with Update 5. Any idea what I could be doing wrong?

This is image is the visual studio publish pane output:
[Visual Studio cloud service deployment logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QyUuG.png)

Comment: facing with the same issue, have you got it done? Thanks!

Comment: .Yes I figured it out in the long run. It occurs when there's low bandwidth or unstable internet connection.It's just bad exception reporting in Azure SDK. I think Microsoft  AZURE SDK should say unstable connection or more leading error message than that generic **Warning: Request was Aborted:Request was Canceled**